# Programatically select a node in a SmartGWT treegrid

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have a smartgwt treegrid, which, when expanding a group, I need to automatically select the first childnode of that group. I can get to the child, but I fail to see how to select the node.

```
    TreeGrid moduleTree = new TreeGrid();
    final Tree tree = new Tree();
    moduleTree.addFolderOpenedHandler(new FolderOpenedHandler() {

        public void onFolderOpened(FolderOpenedEvent event) {
            TreeNode[] children = tree.getChildren(event.getNode());
            if (children.length > 0) {
                // TODO
            }
        }
    });
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a llok at http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can select a particular **TreeNode** using this property of **TreeGrid**:

```
treeGrid().selectRecord(record);
treeGrid().selectRecords(records);
```

Here *record* is the **TreeNode** you want to be selected. You can select multiple **TreeNodes** using the second property.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that TreeNode is also a record. A bit counterintuitive, but it works!

Comment: Is anyone familiar with the automatic expansion of nodes when selecting a child/leaf `TreeNode` ?

Comment: Do you mean expansion of parent node while selecting chile node?

Comment: How to do the same with Smartgwt ColumnTree when   ColumnTree .setShowMultipleColumns(true);

Comment: @mor222, ColumnTree also has the same methods available: `columnTree.selectRecord(record)` and `columnTree.selectRecords(records)`. 
Please see this documentation: https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ColumnTree.html#selectRecord-int-

Comment: @RAS, I have already tried that, it only expands the first column, but it doesn't open the second and third and other lower columns.